# solving a math expression

Tags: c#, math

I want to evaluate a math expression which the user enters in a textbox. I have done this so far

```
string equation, finalString;
equation = textBox1.Text;
StringBuilder stringEvaluate = new StringBuilder(equation);
stringEvaluate.Replace("sin", "math.sin");
stringEvaluate.Replace("cos", "math.cos");
stringEvaluate.Replace("tan", "math.tan");
stringEvaluate.Replace("log", "math.log10");
stringEvaluate.Replace("e^", "math.exp");
finalString = stringEvaluate.ToString();
StringBuilder replaceI = new StringBuilder(finalString);
replaceI.Replace("x", "i");

double a;
for (int i = 0; i<5 ; i++)
 {
  a = double.Parse(finalStringI);
  if(a<0)
    break;
 }
```

when I run this program it gives an error `"Input string was not in a correct format."` and highlights `a=double.Parse(finalStringI);`

I used a pre defined expression a=i*math.log10(i)-1.2 and it works, but when I enter the same thing in the textbox it doesn't.
I did some search and it came up with something to do with compiling the code at runtime.

any ideas how to do this?
i'm an absolute beginner.
thanks :)

Comment: There aren't any utilities in the framework to evaluate arbitrary expression strings as you are trying to do.  It would be better to actually parse the string and write the logic to perform the evaluations.  As you have it right now, there is no easy way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JeffMercado: It's always dangerous to say "There's nothing in the framework", because it's so easy to be wrong.  It happens that you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is within your `stringEvaluate` StringBuilder. When you're replacing "sin" with "math.sin", the content within `stringEvaluate` is still a string. You've got the right idea, but the error you're getting is because of that fact.

`Math.sin` is a method inside the `Math` class, thus it cannot be operated on as you are in your `a = double.Parse(finalStringI);` call.

It would be a pretty big undertaking to accomplish your goal, but I would go about it this way:

1. Create a class (perhaps call it Expression).
2. Members of the Expression class could include Lists of operators and operands, and perhaps a double called `solution`.
3. Pass this class the string at instantiation, and tear it apart using the `StringBuilder` class. For example, if you encounter a "sin", add `Math.sin` to the operator collection (of which I'd use type object).
4. Each operator and operand within said string should be placed within the two collections.
5. Create a method that evaluates the elements within the operator and operand collection accordingly. This could get sticky for complex calculations with more than 2 operators, as you would have to implement a PEMDAS-esque algorithm to re-order the collections to obey the order of operations (and thus achieve correct solutions).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The `.Parse` methods (`Int.Parse`, `double.Parse`, etc) will ***only*** take a string such as "25" or "3.141" and convert it to the matching value type (int 25, or double 3.141).  They will not evaluate math expressions!

You'll pretty much have to write your own text-parser and parse-tree evaluator, or explore run-time code-generation, or MSIL code-emission.

Neither topic can really be covered in the Q&A format of StackOverflow answers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/CodeDomCalculator08082005003253AM/CodeDomCalculator.aspx

It sounds like it does pretty much what you're trying to do. Evaluating math expressions is not as simple as just parsing a `double` (which is really only going to work for strings like "1.234", not "1 + 2.34"), but apparently it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval` function that the framework includes for JScript.NET code.

More details: http://odetocode.com/code/80.aspx

Or, if you're not scared to use classes marked "deprecated", it's really easy:

```
static string EvalExpression(string s)
{
    return Microsoft.JScript.Eval.JScriptEvaluate(s, null, Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine.CreateEngine()).ToString();
}
```

For example, input `"Math.cos(Math.PI / 3)"` and the result is `"0.5"` (which is the correct cosine of 60 degrees)